# Is the a way to plot preimages of points/set of functions?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Suppose I have a function f:A ->A. I can plot this function in a cartesian coordinate system in tikz/pgf. Can someone explain to me how to plot for a specific point a in A and a natural number m the m-time preimage of a (meaning the point in A, that evaluates to a, if f is m times applied) ?

Is it also possible to plot the preimage of an entire subset, that consists of more than a single point, of A ?

Comment: Can you please give a concrete example of what you want to achive, the function etc... In general TeX is a Turing complete machine and given infinite patience and skills anything is possible, perhaps not through tikz.

Comment: Depends on the function itself. If it is possible to be expressed as an admissible function in TikZ/PGF or better `pgfplots` then it might be possible through nested foreach loops.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides For example any linear function ax+b would interest me.

Answer (score 2):

`TikZ/pfg` won't do this for you; it is not a computer algebra system. Given `f` and `m`, you need to compute the proper pre-image yourself. Then, of course, `TikZ/pgf` can plot the points you specify.

Comment: Couldn't perhaps gnuplot be used in combination with tikz ? I think I remember seeing somewhere a piece of code, where some function was actually computed in gnuplot and the plottet with tikz.

Comment: Probably. I wasn't thinking in those terms in my answer. I'll update my answer if I get time to think about how to send the parameter `m` to gnuplot.

Comment: Since some time has passed, I'm curious if you managed to come up with something...